# Why does IDEA give warning when returning a Future of None?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

For the following snippet IDEA gives a warning, that `future {None}` would be redundant:

```scala
queryString match {
  case Some(query) => ... // Do async call
  case None        => future { None }
}
```

Is there a better possibility to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an already set future without spawning a closure, using `Future.successful[T](result: T)`, so maybe `Future.successful(None)` is what you want.

Since futures already distinguish between success and failure independent of their type parameter, however, you could signalise a failure also through `Future.failed(new Exception("No query string"))`, given that your async call can also omit the wrapping in `Some`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if IDEA's warning is helpful in this case.

You could potentially silence it by pushing the matching down into the future:

```
future {
    queryString match {
        case Some(query) => Some(computeResult(query))
        case None => None
    }
}
```

(or more briefly: `future { queryString.map(computeResult(_)) }`)

Answer (score 1):

I think i solved it by myself: I don't need an Option encapsulated in my Future, because the Future itself can also fail and therefore an failure is kind of equal to a None.

Now i only return a Future and:

```
queryString match {

  case Some(query) =>
    //async Call which returns a Future without Option
  case None => throw new Exception("Error")
}
```

Comment: Throwing exceptions is a pretty heavyweight and not always very desirable means of handling a missing value.

Comment: But Failures in futures seem to be handled by Exceptions in the most tutorials. See here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/futures-promises.html#functional_composition_and_forcomprehensions

Comment: A `Future[Option[T]]` can return `Success(None)` to mean "nothing went wrong with the processing, but the value you wanted is not there".